Error when installing salesforce code scanner
I am trying to install salesforce code scanner with
sf plugins install @salesforce/sfdx-scanner but I am getting an error:

NpmError: Failed to find @salesforce/sfdx-scanner@latest in the registry

sf --version gives:

@salesforce/cli/2.22.7 linux-x64 node-v20.14.0

If I try to update sf cli with sudo npm update --global @salesforce/cli I get:
npm error code 1
npm error path /usr/local/lib/node_modules/@salesforce/cli
npm error command failed
npm error command sh -c node ./scripts/preinstall.js

I have the sf cli globally installed.
Any ideas?

Can you try the following ?
sudo npm install @salesforce/cli@latest -g


Same error, this is from the npm debug log
173 verbose stack Error: command failed
173 verbose stack     at ChildProcess. (/snap/node/8723/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/@npmcli/promise-spawn/lib/index.js:53:27)
173 verbose stack     at ChildProcess.emit (node:events:519:28)
173 verbose stack     at maybeClose (node:internal/child_process:1105:16)
173 verbose stack     at ChildProcess._handle.onexit (node:internal/child_process:305:5)
